# Not working jQuery ajax to insert data into the database in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-ajaxq

I can't figure out what error I have in my code. I have checked carefully and tried to insert data into a SQL Server database. But every time it shows "Internal server error" while submitting the form. Please help me to figure out. Thanks

Here is my code..

Database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Doctor] 
(
    [DoctorID]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DoctorCardID]    AS ('DOC' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT (VARCHAR (3), [DoctorID]), (3))),
    [DoctorName]      VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    [Gender]          VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [ContactNumber]   VARCHAR(11)  NOT NULL,
    [DoctorAvatar]    VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    [Dob]             DATE         NULL,
    [Address]         VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [City]            VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [ZipCode]         NCHAR(10)    NULL,
    [QualificationID] INT          NULL,
    [SpecialityID]    INT          NULL,
    [JoiningDate]     DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [AddeddDate]      DATE         NULL,
    [IsActive]        BIT          DEFAULT ((1)) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DoctorID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([QualificationID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Qualification] ([QualificationID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([SpecialityID]) 
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Speciality] ([SpecialityID])
);
```

Jquery and Ajax code:

```
$('#doctor-submit').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = JSON.stringify({
                        DoctorName: $('#DoctorName').val(),
                        Gender: $('#Gender').val(),
                        ContactNumber: $('#ContactNumber').val(),
                        Dob: $('#Dob').val(),
                        Address: $('#Address').val(),
                        City: $('#City').val(),
                        ZipCode: $('#ZipCode').val(),
                        QualificationID: $('#QualificationID').val(),
                        SpecialityID: $('#SpecialityID').val(),
                        JoiningDate: $('#JoiningDate').val(),
                        AddeddDate: $('#AddeddDate').val(),
                        IsActive: $('#IsActive').val()
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Doctor")",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,
                    processData : false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType:"json",
                    cache:false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#show-success').show();
                    }

                });
            });
```

ASP.NET MVC form:

```
<form id="DoctorForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Doctor</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "DoctorName" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Gender" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ContactNumber" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dob, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dob, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dob" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dob, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Address" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "City" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZipCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ZipCode" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QualificationID, "QualificationID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.DropDownList("QualificationID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "QualificationID" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QualificationID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SpecialityID, "SpecialityID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SpecialityID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SpecialityID" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SpecialityID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JoiningDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JoiningDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "JoiningDate" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JoiningDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddeddDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddeddDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "AddeddDate" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddeddDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsActive, new { @id = "IsActive" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input id="doctor-submit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/man.jpg" id="processImage" class="process-image img-responsive" />
                        <div class="upload-box">
                            <input id="imageFile" name="ImageUpload" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" alt="Photo" class="image-file" />
                            <div class="upload-icon">
                                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="show-success" class="success-save alert alert-block alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i>
    </button>

    <p>
        <strong>
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i>
            Well done!
        </strong>
        Doctor Save successfully!
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create( Doctor doctor)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (doctor.ImageUpload != null)
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(doctor.ImageUpload.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(doctor.ImageUpload.FileName);
            filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            doctor.DoctorAvatar = "~/Content/images/DoctorsImg/" + filename;
            doctor.ImageUpload.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/DoctorsImg"), filename));
        }

        db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctor");
    }

    ViewBag.QualificationID = new SelectList(db.Qualifications, "QualificationID", "QualificationName", doctor.QualificationID);
    ViewBag.SpecialityID = new SelectList(db.Specialities, "SpecialityID", "SpecialityTag", doctor.SpecialityID);

    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with **ValidateAntiForgeryToken** as you are not submitting the form. You are making an Ajax request hence the anti forgery token validation fails. Remove this and try again.

Comment: Thank you @rohit-manocha. I have tried but problem is same. still have Internal server error